# Origin of about:blank in regards to same origin policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The same origin policy dictates two pages may share JavaScript resources if they share protocol, host and port.

What is the origin of the `about:blank` page in Chrome? That is, what is the protocol, host and port of the page? What pages can it share JavaScript resources with?

Comment: The origin must be JavaScript wizards

Comment: `about:blank` is *old*. I am not sure where it was defined or first implemented, but I am pretty sure predates JavaScript itself as a way to get to a "blank page" (e.g. "no home page" scenarios).

Comment: I think the OP means origin as in how does cross-origin restrictions apply to it, not origin as in 'what events lead to its creation'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `about:` scheme is considered to make for [a unique origin](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/platform/SchemeRegistry.cpp&exact_package=chromium&type=cs&l=68), which [disallows](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/loader/CrossOriginAccessControl.cpp&exact_package=chromium&type=cs&l=146) access to *any* resource - even `about:blank` to itself.